# convert reducer from react redux to hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a login/ registration app. I am trying to convert a reducer for a class based component to use with hooks. This is the reducer :

```
import { SET_CURRENT_USER, USER_LOADING } from "../actions/types";

const isEmpty = require("is-empty");

const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: {},
  loading: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CURRENT_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: !isEmpty(action.payload),
        user: action.payload
      };
    case USER_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

How can I convert this to reducer for use in hooks functional component?

This is my login component:

```
function Login (props) {
 
      const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
      const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
      const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);
 useEffect(() => {
    if (props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }
  });
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }
  }, [props.auth]);
const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const userData = {
      email: email,
      password: password
    };

    props.loginUser(userData);
  };
 form data....
```

Comment: you need to create actions for each action types and then you can import them into your login component and dispatch the action where you require it.

Comment: export const loginUser = userData => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/login", userData)
    .then(res => {
      // Save to localStorage

      // Set token to localStorage
      const { token } = res.data;
      localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
      // Set token to Auth header
      setAuthToken(token);
      // Decode token to get user data
      const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
      // Set current user
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data..

Comment: This is my actions code.

Answer (score 0):

import your action into your component and dispatch it.

dispatch(yourAction());

You can pass a payload if needed.

Comment: const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { loginUser }
)(Login);
This was the previous dispatcher for class component, I am trying to convert it to functional component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useDispatch, useSelector` from `react-redux`

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const dispatch = useDispatch();

const user = useSelector(getUser); 
// you can pass your selector function to useSelector(state => state.user)
```

Inside `useEffect` Hook you can use `dispatch()` to dispatch your action

```
 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(your action goes here);
  },[])
```